# Adding 2 Sidebars To The Right

Tags: css, layout

Hello i have tried to make my website theme (drupal zen) to have both sidebars on the right. As you can see from my link something somewhere has gone wrong
[my website where something has gone wrong](http://onlinebanter.com/chat)

Ive been fiddling about with all sorts of things to make it all align but it's driving me mad. Mental even. Its all this negative margin business thats beyond my knowledge.

Could anyone suggest any fixes for me before i give up trying to make a website forever.

Thanks

:(

Comment: sorry i should add that i have a fixed width 1000px wide page. i was wanting the right most sidebar to be 125px and the left/right sidebar to be 200px. thanks

Comment: You've a problem with the main column on the left I guess: `#main-wrapper` has a width of 600px and its grand-child `.two-sidebars #content` has a width of 635px. Is it intended? As a rule, once a parent has a desired width, don't fix any width to its descendants as they already have `width: auto` by default because they are blocks and "will expand".

Answer (score 1):

This moves your sidebar container to the right side, is it what you want?

```
#sidebars-custom{float: right}
```

Those add the desired width to your inner sidebars:

```
.region-sidebar-first {width: 200px}
.region-sidebar-second {width: 125px}
```

Comment: thanks for the replies folks. No sorry Cadence i was wanting the main content on the left and the two sidebars on the right. I think Felipe might have hit upon the problem. Let me sort something out and i will try changing th main wrapper width to 635px and report back. again thanks for all your time

Comment: sorted it was the wrapper width Felipe. I had added the css file from somewhere else and missed it being there. Again thank you very much.

Comment: mmm still a problem with some pages which i cannot get rid of. see here for example http://onlinebanter.com/crash-bang-wallop both sidebars slipped off to the right. I cant seem to find out why either.

Comment: ah i might have sorted it. it was the #page .messages. soz dont mind me. just up